# In JAVA code, not running in the Google environment, how does one use a trained translation model?

Tags: translation, automl, google-translation-api

I seem to be missing something obvious, I think.  We've been using the Google Translation API for a while now, and now we want to "upgrade" to a custom trained model instead of the default nmt.

We've uploaded our texts, trained it, and now have a model.  In the predict tab on the Google console, it works great.  so, now what?

This is the code that we use today:

```
        translate = TranslateOptions
            .newBuilder()
            .setCredentials(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(googleCredentials))
            .build()
            .getService();

                translate.translate(
                    text,
                    TranslateOption.sourceLanguage(fromLng),
                    TranslateOption.targetLanguage(toLng),
                    TranslateOption.model(model));
```

where model is "nmt" (or "base")... should I just be able to drop in my newly trained model code that was created when the training finished?  When I try, it comes back with a 400 error and the message:

```
   "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Invalid Value",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid Value"
```

Trying different code as documented here: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/quickstart-client-libraries-v3
yields other errors like: "INFO: Failed to detect whether we are running on Google Compute Engine."

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here we go... for the next person looking to do this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-automl</artifactId>
    <version>0.97.0-beta</version>
</dependency>
```

code:

```
private PredictionServiceClient predictionClient; 
private ModelName modelName; 

public GoogleTranslationServiceTrained(final byte[] googleCredentials) throws IOException {
    super();

    PredictionServiceSettings settings = PredictionServiceSettings
            .newBuilder()
            .setCredentialsProvider(new CredentialsProvider() {
                @Override
                public Credentials getCredentials() throws IOException {
                    return ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(googleCredentials));
                }
            }).build();

    // Instantiate client for prediction service.
    predictionClient = PredictionServiceClient.create(settings);

    // Get the full path of the model.
    modelName = ModelName.of("xxxx", "us-central1", "yyy");
}

public String getRemoteTranslate(String text) {
    TextSnippet textSnippet = TextSnippet.newBuilder().setContent(text).build();

    // Set the payload by giving the content of the file.
    ExamplePayload payload = ExamplePayload.newBuilder().setTextSnippet(textSnippet).build();

    // Additional parameters that can be provided for prediction
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

    PredictResponse response = predictionClient.predict(modelName, payload, params);
    TextSnippet translatedContent = response.getPayload(0).getTranslation().getTranslatedContent();

    return StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(translatedContent.getContent());

}
```